# How to mock a module that is required in another module with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, mocking, jasmine-node

```
const Client = require('./src/http/client');

module.exports.handler = () => {
    const client = new Client();
    const locationId = client.getLocationId(123);
};
```

How can I test this module asserting that the `client.getLocationId` has been called with the `123` argument in Jasmine?

I know how to achieve that with Sinon, but I have no clue about Jasmine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where with Sinon you would do:

```
Sinon.spy(client, 'getLocationId');

...

Sinon.assert.calledWith(client.getLocationId, 123);
```

with Jasmine you do:

```
spyOn(client, 'getLocationId');

...

expect(client.getLocationId).toHaveBeenCalledWith(123);
```

---

**Update:** So, what you need is to mock the `Client` module when it's required by the module you're testing. I suggest using [Proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) for this:

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const mockedClientInstance = {
  getLocationId: () => {}
};
const mockedClientConstructor = function() {
  return mockedClientInstance;
};

const moduleToTest = proxyquire('moduleToTest.js', {
  './src/http/client': mockedClientConstructor
});
```

This will inject your mock as a dependency so that when the module you're testing requires `./src/http/client`, it will get your mock instead of the real `Client` module. After this you just spy on the method in `mockedClientInstance` as normal:

```
spyOn(mockedClientInstance, 'getLocationId');
moduleToTest.handler();
expect(mockedClientInstance.getLocationId).toHaveBeenCalledWith(123);
```

Comment: The problem is that in my tests, I cannot get access to the `client` instance, therefore i cannot spy on any of the methods.

Comment: @kekko12 Well that shouldn't make any difference between Sinon and Jasmine. You mentioned that you know how to achieve it with Sinon. How would you do that? Any solution for that should work fine with Jasmine.

Comment: Actually I thought I knew, but I just tried and that is not working. It works only if the required module is a instance (singleton). I guess that the only option is to use Proxyquire.

Comment: proxyquire is the way to go